# Read XML element based on attribute without knowing name of parent

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using a webservice that gives a response in XML. When an error has occurred, somewhere in the XML is an attribute msg. The problem is, that based on the request, the attribute msg in the response can belong to different elements. In one situation the attr can belong to the element Dimension and in another situation to the element Period. Dimension is the root element, but Period is a child of Transaction.

Every solution I see, assumes that you know the name of the parent element, which in my case can be different.

What I need is code to find the element where the attribute msg and msgtype belong to, so that based on that, I can find the rest of the information like name or invoice number.

This is my code that wil easily find the msg in the first xml example, but not in the second.

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Temp\Response.xml");

string element = xml.Root.Name.ToString(), text = "", msg = "", naam = "";


var nodes = (from n in xml.Descendants(element)
                    where n.Attribute("msgtype").Value == "error"
                select new
                {
                    naam = n.Element("name")
                    ,  msg = n.Attribute("msg")
                }).ToList();

foreach (var n in nodes)
{
    text += n.msg.ToString();
    Response.Write(text);
}
```

First XML

```
<dimension msgtype="error" msg="De code voldoet niet aan het formaat 1[0-9][0-9][0-9]." result="0">
<office>ZKF000324</office>
<type>DEB</type>
<code>14</code>
<name>Bedrijf 113</name>
<shortname>Bedrijf 113</shortname>
</dimension>
```

Second XML

```
<transaction result="0" destiny="temporary">
<header result="0">
<office shortname="Twinfield" name="Pietersen">ZKF000324</office>
<code shortname="Verkoop" name="Verkoopfactuur">VRK</code>
<currency shortname="EuroK" name="Euro naam">EUR</currency>
<period result="0" msg="Jaar 2020 moet tussen 1965 en 2019 liggen.//Jaar 2020 moet tussen 1965 en 2019 liggen.//Jaar 2020 moet tussen 1965 en 2019 liggen.//De combinatie van het jaar en de periode bestaat niet." msgtype="error">2020/05</period>
<date result="0" msg="Datum 12/05/2020 valt buiten de opgegeven periode (2020/05)." msgtype="warning">20200512</date>
<invoicenumber>2016112</invoicenumber>
</transaction>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through the entire tree: `Descendants()`.

Note the use of Null-conditional operator `?.`

```
var nodes = (from n in xml.Descendants()
             where n.Attribute("msgtype")?.Value == "error"
             select new
             {
                 msg = n.Attribute("msg")
             })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Just casting the attribute to `string` would do it as well, as the conversion operator will return `null` for a null `XAttribute`.